# Does the word 'foreign' apply to Irish in Bishop's transcripts from English Baptism records 18th century

Tags: birth-records, ireland, transcriptions, worcestershire

I'm researching English records and came across a Bishop's transcript of a baptism in Worcestershire. The year is 1789.

The records says: "Sarah daughter of Samuel and Mary Brooks   Foreign". The 'foreign' is aligned to the right of the page and is also recorded against some other records. Brooks doesn't sound too far afield, so I'm wondering if Irish immigrants would have been classed as foreign in this context?

Can anyone advise if there's a way of determining if that is true?

Comment: Could just mean someone who wasn't from the local area and lived outside of that particular parish.

Comment: Not someone from outside the parish.  Someone from another diocese.

Comment: @Chenmunka - possible. But do you have evidence why you believe it to be outside the diocese, rather than outside the parish?

Comment: Could the designation refer to the entry rather than the person?

Comment: The Bishop's transcript is for the entire county, in this case Worcestershire, so parish and diocese boundaries would be irrelevant in that context.